# Can 4.4 be downloaded OTA without wifi?

Tags: nexus-4, ota-update, 4.4-kitkat

My phone have gotten a 4.4 system update available notification, but it is not downloading it. There is a small text saying “Only over WiFi until 21:06”. Does that mean that my phone will start downloading the update at that time unless I connect to a wifi network? How can I start the update now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now download it using your network only, no need for wifi. The wifi only option was until 23 November. I'm currently downloading 4.4 over my mobile internet only.

Comment: It seem to have resolved itself. Woke up to 4.4 today. No wifi involved.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just change the date in your system to sometime in the future. This should trick your phone into downloading it now.

Comment: This should be the accepted reply, it still works for 6.x OTA's. Although you might want to turn the clock back *before* pressing the install button, after download completes.